How to use 2 different LiveSpeechRecognizer(different lm and dic) or 1 that can change lm and dic?
When there is only one recognizer with one config there is no problem... So when i use one recognizer and changing config with difference lm and dic it gives java.lang.IllegalStateException error because of this code, stoping the recognizer not working too
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");
            configuration.setDictionaryPath("src/main/resources/words.dic");
            configuration.setLanguageModelPath("src/main/resources/words.lm");
            LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);

            Configuration configuration2 = new Configuration();
            configuration2.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");
            configuration2.setDictionaryPath("src/main/resources/words2.dic");
            configuration2.setLanguageModelPath("src/main/resources/words2.lm");
            LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer2 = new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration2);


java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 16000.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.

I tried:
Using 2 different or same recognizers,
Using 1 recognizer and changing config,
And whatever came to my mind.

Can you please provide a [mre] so we can see how you configure your first and second instance? It's enough if the example just shows the failing of the line of code you already posted.

If i write more than one  LiveSpeechRecognizer (recognizername) = new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configname);
it gives that error

Although this is not a [mre] because I cannot compile the code and run it, I have an idea: you start two live speech recognizers that probably want to open the same audio input device twice - and that device doesn't support that probably. I do not have experience with Sphinx4 but I would try to use two StreamSpeechRecognizers instead and feed them the same data. This will involve maybe involve multithreading etc. so is not an easy task. You could also try to record the audio first into a file and then run the two recognizers one after another.

I'm new here sorry, I tried what you said and it worked thanks for helping!
